# UnauthorizedAccessException while saving a XML file

Tags: c#, xml, exception

I'm developing a C# Windows Forms Application that is connected to a DB using a WebService.
While saving a XML config file, it's throwing an UnauthorizedAccessException.
Here's the function responsible for the XML file creation (it's inside a class called MyXmlHandler):

```
public void CreateConfigXML(string path)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDeclaration dec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);

        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("configuration");
        doc.AppendChild(root);

        XmlElement epubfolder = doc.CreateElement("epubfolder");
        epubfolder.InnerText = @"C:\";
        XmlElement webservicelink = doc.CreateElement("webservicelink");
        webservicelink.InnerText = "http://localhost:20707/Service1.svc";

        root.AppendChild(epubfolder);
        root.AppendChild(webservicelink);

        doc.Save(path);
    }
```

And here's where I'm using the function:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        ...

        string xmlPath = Application.StartupPath + @"\Config\Config.xml";
        string xsdPath = Application.StartupPath + @"\Config\Config.xsd";
        MyXmlHandler xmlHandler = new MyXmlHandler(xmlPath, xsdPath);

        if (Directory.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\Config") && File.Exists(xmlPath) && File.Exists(xmlPath) && xmlHandler.ValidateXml())
        {
            Application.Run(form);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\Config"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath + @"\Config");
            }

            xmlHandler.CreateConfigXML(Application.StartupPath + @"\Config");
            MessageBox.Show(xmlHandler.ValidateMessage);
        }

    }
}
```

It's throwing the exception at doc.Save(path)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a directory path to your `CreateConfigXML` function. Try this: `Application.StartupPath + @"\Config\config.xml"`

Edit: Or rather `CreateConfigXML(xmlPath)`